# How can i write a loop in R to create a new variable, which would calculate the distance between the current trial and its last occurrence?

Tags: r, loops

[image]![enter image description here][2]I have a data set, which contains the lists of the 8 words(e.g. "klein", "warm"), occurring in a random pattern. I need to create a variable which shows me how many trials were in between the particular occurrence of the word and its last occurrence. for example, if the word showed up twice in a row, this new variable should be 0, if there was another word in between, the variable would be 1 and so on. can anyone help me and give me a hint?
thank you in advance!
P.s. you can see the picture is how it is done in SPSS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv3WA.png)

P.s. dput()

```
structure(list(ExperimentName = c("Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", 
"Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment", "Habit_Experiment"
), Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), AccP = c(90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 
90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 
90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 
90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 
90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461, 90.38461), Age = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L), Handedness = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("links", "rechts"), class = "factor"), 
    PracFail.RT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Sex = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("divers", 
    "männlich", "weiblich"), class = "factor"), Block = 1:30, 
    Colour = c("YELLOW", "RED", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", 
    "RED", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "YELLOW", "RED", "RED", 
    "RED", "RED", "YELLOW", "RED", "RED", "YELLOW", "RED", "RED", 
    "YELLOW", "RED", "YELLOW", "RED", "RED", "YELLOW", "DODGERBLUE", 
    "LIME", "DODGERBLUE", "LIME"), contingency.RESP = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), contWord = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    Correct = c("l", "d", "l", "l", "l", "d", "l", "l", "l", 
    "l", "d", "d", "d", "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", 
    "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", "l", "d", "l", "d"), Data = 1:30, 
    Data.Sample = 1:30, Rare_C = c("", "", "True", "False", "False", 
    "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", 
    "False", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False", "True", 
    "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", 
    "", "", "True", "False"), Stim.ACC = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Stim.CRESP = c("l", 
    "d", "l", "l", "l", "d", "l", "l", "l", "l", "d", "d", "d", 
    "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", "d", "l", "d", "d", 
    "l", "l", "d", "l", "d"), Stim.RESP = c("d", "d", "d", "l", 
    "l", "d", "l", "l", "l", "l", "d", "d", "d", "d", "l", "d", 
    "d", "l", "d", "d", "d", "d", "l", "d", "d", "l", "d", "d", 
    "l", "d"), Stim.RT = c(NA, 808L, NA, 691L, 462L, 884L, 443L, 
    466L, 444L, 385L, 474L, 441L, 399L, 347L, 398L, 418L, 383L, 
    451L, 304L, 389L, NA, 467L, 395L, 338L, 333L, 327L, NA, 562L, 
    460L, 374L), Word = c("XXXX", "XXXX", "warm", "leicht", "leicht", 
    "warm", "klein", "ganz", "leicht", "leicht", "klein", "klein", 
    "warm", "ganz", "warm", "leicht", "leicht", "ganz", "ganz", 
    "klein", "ganz", "warm", "ganz", "warm", "klein", "klein", 
    "XXXX", "XXXX", "weich", "klar")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I added a picture in the description of the question, which shows how this was done in SPSS. it may be helpful.

Comment: I tried it out and added the picture

Comment: thanks, I did it and added a  short version in the question

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't need a loop to do this. Here is a possible solution using the `dplyr` package.

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, here I first used `select` to remove other columns for demonstration. You can remove this line to keep your other columns in your data frame.

Next, add trial numbers to each row in your data for each subject. Then if you use `group_by` for each `Subject` and `Word`, you can calculate `last_occurrence` which is difference in trial values for that `Word`.

Words appearing the first time will be `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(Subject, Word) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(trial = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Subject, Word) %>%
  mutate(last_occurrence = trial - lag(trial) - 1)
```

**Output**

```
   Subject Word   trial last_occurrence
     <int> <chr>  <int>           <dbl>
 1       1 XXXX       1              NA
 2       1 XXXX       2               0
 3       1 warm       3              NA
 4       1 leicht     4              NA
 5       1 leicht     5               0
 6       1 warm       6               2
 7       1 klein      7              NA
 8       1 ganz       8              NA
 9       1 leicht     9               3
10       1 leicht    10               0
11       1 klein     11               3
12       1 klein     12               0
13       1 warm      13               6
14       1 ganz      14               5
15       1 warm      15               1
16       1 leicht    16               5
17       1 leicht    17               0
18       1 ganz      18               3
19       1 ganz      19               0
20       1 klein     20               7
21       1 ganz      21               1
22       1 warm      22               6
23       1 ganz      23               1
24       1 warm      24               1
25       1 klein     25               4
26       1 klein     26               0
27       1 XXXX      27              24
28       1 XXXX      28               0
29       1 weich     29              NA
30       1 klar      30              NA
```